# Electron: Store user editable data in .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, electron-builder

I am making an electron app that converts data from .txt files to Javascript arrays. This data is stored inside a folder called `faces` in the main directory. I also have a button in my app which, when clicked opens file explorer at the `faces` folder so the user can edit the .txt files. This works fine when running `npm start`, but then when I use electron builder to package my app, the app can no longer find the .txt files and the user cannot edit them (giving me lots of errors). Is there some way to have a folder of .txt files that the app uses to draw information from with Electron builder?

> Edit

Below is the JS used:

```js
//Import Lists from .txt files

var ears = fs.readFileSync('faces/ears.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');
var mouths = fs.readFileSync('faces/mouths.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');
var eyes = fs.readFileSync('faces/eyes.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');

//Opens faces txt docs in file explorer

function edit() {
    shell.openItem(require('electron').remote.app.getAppPath() + '/faces')
}
```

Here is what happens when I open the packaged app (this is the win-unpacked result but the error is the same for .exe which runs with the installer):

[image: Screen Shot]

As you can see it does not load an information and you can see it cannot find the `faces` folder or the .txt files.

Comment: And what errors do you have? Probably paths can be broken.

Comment: @ArturasLapinskas I'll add the error the question

Comment: You probably should use __Dir to declare the path of your files

Comment: How do I do this

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the path-joining character is different in each OS.

You can see that every slash was backslash(`\`) before your suffix, `/faces`.

Try using `path` module.

```
const path = require(path)

....

function edit() {
  shell.openItem(
    path.resolve(require('electron').remote.app.getAppPath(), 'faces')
  )
}
```

Comment: I now get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'path' before initialization
    at render.js:2` ( I am running this in renderer process if that helps )

Comment: The above error was because there was no quotes in the `require()` statement, however your solution does not solve the problem, it still says the file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The builded app is trying to write in the app folder itself. This is possible in dev, but not in production since che app became an asar archive. (app.asar). If you look at the error your app is trying to write inside app.asas, which is not a folder. So it's not possible to write inside it.

You probably want to save these kind of information not in the path where the application has been installed, but in some of the paths related with user config/preferences.

This: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname may help you retrive the right path.